# Next.js API URL problem on Docker container

Tags: docker, api, next.js

My problem is:

I made a simple web page with Next.js. I take some content from /pages/api/ endpoints with JSON format and show it in pages and components. Compiling locally (npm run dev or npm run start) is fine. When I run it on Docker on Windows 10, I don't have a problem again. And this is working on Heroku and Vercel. The point I'm having trouble with is: I gave the project to the Devops team and they ran it on Docker. They also directed a domain to this project. But the api endpoints are meaninglessly trying to access an ID URL. When I look from Chrome Devtools it looks like this:

http://013cfdde4910:3000/api/en/brands

I get the following errors as console message.

*​Mixed Content: The page at 'https://beta..com/technologies' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://013cfdde4910:3000/api/en/menu'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

Actually it should be http://localhost:3000/api/en/brands. I don't understand where 013cfdde4910 here is coming from and why.

I checked to see if it is among the codes. I looked at the Source of the project that is live, that is, published by the Devops team, from Google Devtools.

_next/static > chunk > pages > _app-eac17e226e00cc01a313.js

When I searched here, I found 013cfdde4910 String in 3 places. Why did it come here when it was built?

For example, the minified code continues as follows.

```
.... return(0,u.useEffect)((function(){fetch("".concat("http://013cfdde4910:3000","/api/").concat(t.locale,"/) brands")).....
```

I can see it as localhost in my local build and when I publish it in Windows 10 Docker and look there. So what is causing the localhost -> 013cfdde4910 conversion and how can I solve it?

Dockerfile I use:

```
FROM node:current-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM base AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /build
COPY --from=base /app ./
RUN npm run build

FROM node:current-alpine AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /build/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /build/public ./public

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

I use docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  ui:
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    env_file:
      - .env
```

And this is next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };
    return config;
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  generateEtags: false,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "tr"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  env: {
    VERSION: process.env.VERSION,
    MODE: process.env.MODE,
    APP_NAME: process.env.APP_NAME,
    HOST: process.env.HOST,
    HOSTNAME: process.env.HOSTNAME,
    PORT: process.env.PORT,
    GA_TRACKING_ID: process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID,
  },
  generateBuildId: async () => {
    return new Date().toDateString();
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `next.config.js` and `package.json` ?

Comment: I added @Ramakay

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the config, it appears the hostname is grabbed as the docker container ID - You do not post the actual fetch code but my guess is - this environment variable is used.

```
   `HOSTNAME: process.env.HOSTNAME`
```

It is either passed as a environment variable or interpreted to be the container ID, you need a way to create a `domain:3000/api/brands` which could be part of the Docker deploy, maybe a nginx proxy.

Comment: I removed the dependencies of process.env.HOST and process.env.HOSTNAME that I used in the project, so I tried it without using it, and the result is as I mentioned. So it's not used in the last Docker deployment.

Comment: Oh ok,  is there a chance to try without the i18n packages ?